# Plotting Error Bars with GNUPLOT

Tags: gnuplot

I can't get gnuplot to make a plot with error bars when my x values are non-numeric.

For an example "data.dat":

```
day        col1  col2
MONDAY     12    4
TUESDAY    10    3
WEDNESDAY  9     2
THURSDAY   11    3
FRIDAY     9     2
SATURDAY   12    3
SUNDAY     8     2
```

I've tried variants of

```
plot "./data.dat" using 2:3:xtic(1) with yerrorlines
plot "./data.dat" using 2:3:xtic(1) with yerrorlines
plot "./data.dat" using 1:2:3 with yerrorlines
```

And get back either `Not enough columns for this style` or 
`warning: Skipping data file with no valid points 
x range is invalid`

What would the `plot` command be to plot (day,col1,col2) => (x,y,y_err)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xtic`, or `xticlabels`, does not count as a data column. That is why `yerrorlines` is complaining about not enough columns. You can provide the implicit column 0 for an enumeration.

```
plot "./data.dat" using 0:2:3:xticlabels(1) with yerrorlines
```

Comment: And when not using `with yerrorlines` there is an implicit column 0 when `plot` doesn't have enough columns? Odd...